# CRMint - Import audiences from BigQuery to Google Analytics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am not sure what's the easiest way to import audiences from BigQuery to Google Analytics. I have a BigQuery table called `dataset_a.georgia` with 2 columns `fullVisitorId (string)` and `predictions (string)`.

[image]

Based on [CRMint documentation](https://google.github.io/crmint/docs/reference/worker_spec.html), there is a worker called `GAAudiencesUpdater` which is doing what I am looking for.  [image: GAAudiencesUpdater Parameters]

However, one of the required parameters is a GA audience JSON template. I have a hard time to understand how exactly I should write this JSON as the [basic JSON example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/remarketingAudience) is pretty long and hard to understand. I just have 2 columns to import, the `fullVisitorId` is already a default variable in Google Analytics while I just created a custom dimension called `predictions` with the index `183` and `user` scope.

I talked to a senior developer who had a bit of experience with CRMint and he suggested me to not use the `GAAudiencesUpdater` because of how hard it is to write the GA audience JSON template. He suggested me to import my BigQuery data into a CSV, store that CSV into Google Cloud Storage before to import that CSV to Google Analytics with the worker to `GADataImporter`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They updated the version. You don't have to import JSON now.

Answer (score 0):

You can find here an example

[GAAudiencesUpdater](https://github.com/google/crmint/issues/42)

> Here's the basic Google Analytics JSON template example:

```
{
  "audienceType": "STATE_BASED",
  "linkedAdAccounts": [
    {
      "linkedAccountId": "{% AW_ACCOUNT_ID %}",
      "type": "ADWORDS_LINKS"
    }
  ],
  "linkedViews": [
    {% GA_VIEW_ID %}
  ],
  "name": "CRMint Tier GA %(tier)i",
  "stateBasedAudienceDefinition": {
    "includeConditions": {
      "daysToLookBack": 7,
      "segment": "users::condition::ga:dimension{% CD_TIER %}=@%(code)s",
      "isSmartList": false,
      "membershipDurationDays": %(duration)i
    },
    "excludeConditions": {
      "segment": "users::condition::ga:dimension{% CD_TIER %}==dur93j#%(tier)ihg@2d6",
      "exclusionDuration": "TEMPORARY"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I also saw that example but I am still confused (i) where I should put instead of `{% AW_ACCOUNT_ID %}` if I am using GCP? (ii). Why is the type `ADWORDS_LINK`? (iii) `=@%(code)s` what is code?

Comment: Still super confusing for me as a junior, there is a lack of documentation on the repo...

Comment: linkedAdAccounts[].type = The type of the foreign account. For example, `ADWORDS_LINKS`, `DBM_LINKS`, `MCC_LINKS` or `OPTIMIZE` and linkedAdAccounts[].accountId = Account ID to which this linked foreign account belongs.

Comment: The =@ is a filter operator: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filterOperators - meaning it contains a substring of the filter condition.